# How to open the terminal from inside a snap application?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, gitkraken, snapcraft

When i am trying to open my repo in the terminal from the Gitkraken GUI. It states:

> There is no terminal configured in your settings. Would you like to configure your terminal now?

Next, I manually set the gnome terminal as `custom terminal command` with `gnome-terminal %d`. The keyword `%d` should be replaced with the repo path. Running this in a terminal works. However in Gitkraken i get:

> Command failed. `gnome-terminal path/to/repo /bin/sh`
>   1: gnome-terminal: not-found

How do i setup gnome terminal as the default terminal for gitkraken. I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

#### Edit:

I see that GitKraken is runnig inside a [snap](https://snapcraft.io). I have broaden the question to how to run a linux command from inside a snap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today i learned about [snap confinement](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-confinement).

> A snap’s confinement level is the degree of isolation it has from your
>   system.

To allow access to your system’s resources in much the same way traditional packages do You should install the snap with the `--classic` parameter.

`snap install gitkraken --classic`

Comment: When doing this, I get "Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap gitkraken".

Comment: hmmm I am on a Arch system now. But maybe run the command with sudo ?